# While statement - Strange output from console after typing keystroke

Tags: c#, while-loop, do-while

Can someone explain why there is strange output on the console either typing `char` or `int`. Please take use window console and tell me why there is numbers such 13- 10 and other number start at such position.

```
namespace TestingVariousLoops
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int someValue;
            do
            {
                someValue = (int)Console.Read();
                Console.WriteLine(someValue);
            }
            while (someValue != 6);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the Console.Read() method is returning the numeric representation ([ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)) of the keyboard character you entered.  To see this, convert it back to a character as such:

```
  Console.WriteLine(someValue + "  char = " + Convert.ToChar(someValue) );
```

Example, I run and enter A, output shows:

```
  65 char = A
```

Answer (score 1):

When you convert a console read to int, you're getting the ASCII values of what you typed in. For example, you hit A and Enter. You'll see 65, 13, 10. This is because 13 is ASCII for carriage return and 10 is line feed. On a Windows system, these two symbols are read by the console when you hit the [Enter] key on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The values being returned are the numeric values of the character you are typing. If you were to cast it to a char it would print exactly what you just typed.